# Window button gone from global menu

Tags: globalmenu

[image]

As seen in the screenshot, the area will hold artefacts of what ever is put over it. I cant access x+- buttons.

In this instance, I had been running google chrome and browsing reddit. I was watching fullscreen video before and the shading of this rectangle were present though video was being rendered correctly in it. In 3D games it is a black rectangle, no rendering in it.

I am running nvidia g210 card with the experimental 310 drivers.

Comment: Can't you provide an image that shows more of the problem area and less of the rest of the screen? Right now, your problem is < 1/100 of the image. Also, were you running something "full screen"? And do mention your graphics.

Comment: Here's another closed question about lingering artifacts: [unresponsive window imprint on the desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/249234/25656).